# Connect to multiple database elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Rails , we can connect to multiple database on fly as,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  database: "db_name", username: "postgres")
```

But in Elixir - Phoenix framework, how to do the same process.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
use Mix.Config

config :my_app, MyApp.OneRepo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL,
  database: "legacy_db",
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  hostname: "something.com"

config :my_app, MyApp.TwoRepo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "some_db_two",
  hostname: "example.com"

config :my_app, ecto_repos: [MyApp.OneRepo, MyApp.TwoRepo]
```

lib/my_app.ex
Supervise the Repos.

```rb
defmodule Databases do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      supervisor(MyApp.OneRepo, []), # <-- our addition
      supervisor(MyApp.TwoRepo, [])     # <-- our addition
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

and finally 
lib/repos.ex

```rb
defmodule MyApp.OneRepo do
 use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app
end

defmodule MyApp.TwoRepo do
 use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app
end
```

example

```rb
iex> import Ecto.Query



 iex> some_table= MyApp.OneRepo.get_by(SomeTable, %{username: "Alpha"})

iex> other_table= MyApp.TwoRepo.all from ot in OtherTable,
             where: ot.user_id == ^user.id
```

Comment: `defmodule databases do` ⇐ the module name should be an atom (either capitalized `Databases` of prepended with a colon `:databases`.)

Comment: This is not "on the fly" though, like OP's Rails example.

Comment: @Dogbert manual explicit `GenServer.start/3` would do, I guess.

Comment: @Dogbert i didnt check that "on the fly" remark. have no idea about that.

Comment: There are multiple databases (single database per client). I think the above wont work

Answer (score 0):

For the raw connection one needs to use the lower abstraction level than `Ecto` provides on top. [`Ecto`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.6/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex#L283-L289) code is the [good source to take an inspiration from](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.6/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex#L283-L289). Basically, for `MySQL` database something like this should do:

```
with {:ok, conn} <- Mariaex.start_link(opts) do
  value = Ecto.Adapters.MySQL.Connection.execute(conn, sql, [], opts)
  GenServer.stop(conn)
  value
end
```

where `opts` is a keyword list with `database`, `username` etc keys. The example of how to maintain a connection pool might be stolen from one of `Ecto` adapters source code as well.

Comment: Here we are stopping the GenServer but not the Sql connection. This makes the SQL connection keeps open. How to solve this

Comment: Negative. `Mariaex` must take care of the underlying connection in her `stop` callback.

Comment: GenServer.stop will stop only the Genserver process but the sql query connection remains idle.